# How to use IgnoreIf in Spock, when I check the variable?

Tags: groovy, spock

I need to skip some functions in the program, but it should depend on a variable defined in the same program. How can I do it?

```
def skip = true

@IgnoreIf({ skip })
def "some function" () {
..
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is by using [spock](/questions/tagged/spock)'s configuration file to include/exclude tests or base classes.

First you create your own annotations and place on your tests.
You then write a Spock configuration file.
When you run your tests you can set the `spock.configuration` property to the configuration file of your choice.
This way you can include/exclude the tests and base classes you want.

Example of spock configuration file:

```
runner {
    println "Run only tests"
    exclude envA
}
```

Your test:

```
@envA
def "some function" () {
    ..
}
```

You can then run :

```
./gradlew test -Pspock.configuration=mySpockConfig.groovy
```

Here is a [github example](https://github.com/roy424/spock-annotations)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by accessing `skip` field in a static context:

```
import spock.lang.IgnoreIf
import spock.lang.Specification

class IgnoreIfSpec extends Specification {

    static boolean skip = true

    @IgnoreIf({ IgnoreIfSpec.skip })
    def "should not execute this test if `IgnoreIfSepc.skip` is set to TRUE"() {
        when:
        def res = 1 + 1

        then:
        res == 2
    }

    def "should execute this test every time"() {
        when:
        def res = 1 + 1

        then:
        res == 2
    }
}
```

Otherwise closure passed to `@IgnoreIf()` tries to find `skip` field inside the closure and it fails.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help you :)

Comment: Well, there's one more important question. How do I change `skip` in the tests? I want to create tests, which set `skip` to true/false, so other tests wouldn't start if the condition wasn't accomplished.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing so. You cannot guarantee the order of tests run and there is a principle that says that every unit test should run in the isolation. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Maybe there is a better solution to that problem?

Comment: Btw, there is a `@Stepwise` annotation that can be added to a test class - it forces spock to run all tests in this class in order and if one fails then all others are ignored. Maybe this a solution worth trying. It forces you to put all depending tests into a single class, but this is uncommon situation. You should always think about your tests as a single unit that does not require anything else to execute and does not depend on the execution of any other test.

Comment: Also updating any static value outside the class is something you should avoid like fire - this is a smell of poor design in general. I hope it helps in finding the best solution to your problem. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to create smoke tests, and if they would fail, other tests wouldn't start. It's not really necessary in the project I'm in, but still wanted to give it a try.

Comment: @woundy Well, maybe in this case [`@Stepwise`](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/extensions.html#_stepwise) annotation will do the trick for you. It will run tests in a single class in order and will ignore rest if one fails. One tip: don't overcomplicate things. Try to fit best to unit testing boundries - don't rely on side effects, don't expect specific order of test classes execution. I don't see any good reason to ignore unit tests if some other test(s) fail(s).

Answer (score 1):

If the variable needs to be computed first and then the decision for test ignoring needs to be taken on the basis of computation, we can use static block and static variable

```
import spock.lang.IgnoreIf
import spock.lang.Specification

class IgnoreIfSpec extends Specification {

    static final boolean skip

    static {
    //some code for computation
    if("some condition")
       skip = true
    else
       skip = false
   }

    @IgnoreIf({ IgnoreIfSpec.skip })
    def "should not execute this test if `IgnoreIfSepc.skip` is set to TRUE"() {
        when:
        def res = 1 + 1

        then:
        res == 2
    }

    def "should execute this test every time"() {
        when:
        def res = 1 + 1

        then:
        res == 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
def skip = true

@IgnoreIf({ instance.skip })
def "some function" () {
..
}
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/docs/extensions.adoc#precondition-context)

**instance**

> The specification instance, if instance fields, shared
> fields, or instance methods are needed. If this property is used, the
> whole annotated element cannot be skipped up-front without executing
> fixtures, data providers and similar. Instead, the whole workflow is
> followed up to the feature method invocation, where then the closure
> is checked, and it is decided whether to abort the specific iteration
> or not.

Then you could do something like:

```
abstract class BaseTest extends Specification {
    boolean skip = false
 
    @IgnoreIf({ instance.skip })
    def "some function" () { .. }
}
```

SubSpecification:

```
class GoodTest extends BaseTest {
}
```

```
class SkipTest extends BaseTest {
    boolean skip = true
}
```

In this case, `skip` is a property, but it can be a method.